# Clone a transform stream in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, stream

I'm trying to reuse a couple of transform streams (gulp-like, ie. `concat()` or `uglify()`) across several readable streams. I only have access to the created instances and not the original subclasses.

It does not work out of the box, I get `Error: stream.push() after EOF` when I pipe at lease two distinct readable streams into my transforms. Somehow the events do appear to leak from one stream to the other.

I've tried to setup a cloneTransform function to somehow cleanly "fork" into two distincts transforms, however I can't get it to not share events:

`function cloneTransform(transform) {
    var ts = new Transform({objectMode: true});
    ts._transform = transform._transform.bind(ts);
    if(typeof transform._flush !== 'undefined') {
      ts._flush = transform._flush.bind(ts);
    }
    return ts;
  }`

Any alternative idea, existing plugin or solution to address this?

---

#### Update: context

I'm working on a rewrite of the gulp-usemin package, it is hosted [here: gulp-usemin-stream](https://github.com/mgcrea/gulp-usemin-stream/blob/master/index.js), example use [here](https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/blob/master/gulpfile.js#L351).

Basically you parse an index.html looking for comment blocks surrounding styles/scripts declarations, and you want to apply several configurable transformation to theses files (see [grunt-usemin](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin)).
So the problem I'm trying to solve is to reuse an array of transforms, `[concat(), uglify()]` that are passed as options to a gulp meta transform.

Answer (score 1):

you're doing unnecessary work in your code. it should be as simple as:

```
function clone(transform) {
  var ts = new Transform({ objectMode: true})
  ts._transform = transform._transform
  ts._flush = transform._flush
  return ts
}
```

however, i'm not sure how you're trying to use it, so i'm not sure what error you're getting. there's also the issue of initialization where the initial transform stream might initialize the stream with `.queue = []` or something, and you won't be initializing it in your clone.

the solution completely depends on the problem you're trying to solve, and i feel like you're approaching the problem incorrectly in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, 

I'm working on a rewrite of the gulp-usemin package, it is hosted here https://github.com/mgcrea/gulp-usemin-stream, example use here https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/blob/master/gulpfile.js#L351.

Basically you parse an index.html looking for comment blocks surrounding styles/scripts declarations, and you want to apply several configurable transformation to theses files (see https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin).
So the problem I'm trying to solve is to reuse an array of transforms, `[concat(), uglify()]` that are passed as options to a gulp meta transform.

Comment: Your code, nor mine does work. Somehow the events leak from one readdable stream to the other and once the first one gets ended, it breaks the 2nd one.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to use a `Transform` stream directly instead of subclassing it. What you should be doing is subclassing `Transform` and overriding the `_tranform` and, optionally, `_flush` methods. That way, you can just create a new instance of your transform stream for each readable stream that you need to use it with.

**Example:**

```
var util = require('util');
var Transform = require('stream').Transform;

function MyTransform(options) {
    Transform.call(this, options);
    // ... any setup you want to do ...
}
util.inherits(MyTransform, Transform);


MyTransform.protocol._transform = function(chunk, encoding, done) {
    // ... your _transform implementation ...
}

// Optional
MyTransform.protocol._flush = function(done) {
    // ... optional flush implementation ...
}
```

Once you have that setup, you can simply create new instances of `MyTransform` for each stream you want to use it with:

```
var readStream1 = ...
var readStream2 = ...

var transform1 = new MyTransform();
var transform2 = new MyTransform();

readStream1.pipe(transform1).pipe(...);
readStream2.pipe(transform2).pipe(...);
```

Comment: The problem is that I just have access to the given instance, not the original subclass. Streams I want to fork are gulp transform streams like `concat()` or `uglify()`.

Comment: Interesting. Why do you need to clone them or, what's the end result you want? Are you trying to pipe their output to multiple other streams maybe?

Comment: I'm trying to rewrite the `gulp-usemin` task to support async transforms, the transforms come as array from passed options (pipelineIds), eg. you define one css pipeline that can process several blocks. Thought it would be easy, but I did block on this issue. Source here: https://github.com/mgcrea/gulp-usemin-stream/blob/master/index.js#L76